# Is the cross product $A \rtimes H$ a bialgebra?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

Let $H$ be a bialgebra and $A$ a $H$-module algebra. The cross product $A \rtimes H$ is defined as follows. As a vector space $A \rtimes H = A \otimes H$. The multiplication on $A \rtimes H$ is defined as follows:
\begin{align}
(a \otimes h)(b \otimes g) = \sum a(h_{(1)}.b) \otimes h_{(2)}g,
\end{align}
where $a, b \in A$, $h, g \in H$, $\Delta(h) = \sum h_{(1)} \otimes h_{(2)}$.

Is there a comultiplication $\Delta$ on $A \rtimes H$ such that the cross product $A \rtimes H$ is a bialgebra? If $\Delta$ does not always exist, under what conditions there is a comultiplication $\Delta$ on $A \rtimes H$ such that $A \rtimes H$ is a bialgebra? Thank you very much.

Edit: we add one more condition: suppose that $A$ is a bialgebra. In this case, is there a comultiplication $\Delta$ on $A \rtimes H$ such that the cross product $A \rtimes H$ is a bialgebra? If $\Delta$ does not always exist, under what conditions there is a comultiplication $\Delta$ on $A \rtimes H$ such that $A \rtimes H$ is a bialgebra? Thank you very much.

Comment: Take $H$ trivial. Then you're asking whether $A$ always has a bialgebra structure, and there's no reason that should be true.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan, thank you very much. I edited the post.

Comment: And you don't want the assumptions of (double) bosonization?

Comment: @AHusain, thank you very much. Maybe we want the assumptions of double bosonization. I am not very familiar with double bosonization.

Comment: @JianrongLi I think you've said you had Majid's book before, so do you want an explanation as an answer?

Comment: @AHusain, yes, it will be very helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AHusain, which parts of Majid's book is about this problem?

Comment: A bit related to this, in a certain situation the paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9505024v1.pdf Theorem 5.1 gives a Hopf algebroid structure on the smash product (which appears as the total algebra of the Hopf algebroid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case that $A$ is a braided Hopf algebra in $_H^H YD$ you can form $A \# H$ with the multiplication you already wrote down. The coproduct uses the fact that this kind of $A$ also has a left $H$ coaction as well given by $\delta r^{(2)} = r^{(2)}_{(-1)} \otimes r^{(2)}_{(0)}$

$$
\Delta ( r \# h) = ( r^{(1)} \# r^{(2)}_{(-1)} h_{(1)} ) \otimes ( r^{(2)}_{(0)} \# h_{(2)})
$$

If you want finite dimensional $H$, then you can say in terms of modules for $D(H)$.

Chapters 6 and 7 of Foundations of Quantum Group Theory discusses extension problems such as these. See there for compatibility conditions too. You might also look in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869384710118

Comment: in [the paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869384710118), Theorem 2.4, the coproduct is defined as $$\Delta_{B \rtimes H} = \Psi_{B, H} \circ (\Delta_B \otimes \Delta_H).$$
This is different from your formula
$$
\Delta ( r \# h) = ( r^{(1)} \# r^{(2)}_{(-1)} h_{(1)} ) \otimes ( r^{(2)}_{(0)} \# h_{(2)}).
$$
How could we know which coproduct should we use?

Comment: now I understand. The two formulas are the same.